# How is python managing variables in multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Good morning/evening, dear community.

I am currently setting up an analysis routine for a large number of simulations. I want to increase its speed by transforming it into a multithreaded routine, where each thread takes a named file and apply to it my analysis routine. I am working on an HPC server, allowing me to ask for a certain number of cores, thus at the end, I would have 1 core working on 1 file in parallel with X number of cores.

I read a few examples about multithreading and I am well aware of the problem about variables being shared between thread. My question is how does each thread handle its own "thread variables"? If I define a variable inside the thread function, will it be shared with other threads? Do I have to use the lock condition for this to work (if so, threading would not be useful since each thread would need to wait until the completion of all the other threads I believe)

Below is my attempt to thread my analysis routine. The analysis without the threading is working, each of the 'import glob_**' modules is functioning I coded and that I am importing here.

The main_task function is the thread launcher: I have X cores, I create X threads and then assign each thread to the corresponding task, and I do that until all the files (stored in a list "files_to_analyse") are treated. The length_analyse is just the length of this list.

The thread_task function is the analysis routine that I tried to transform: taking a file name stored in a list (files_to_analyse) and calling the block modules I coded and transformed in global functions. In this function I create variables that will store the information of the simulation that is being treated, thus if there are some errors with these variables, it would lead to analysis errors (for example the file variable, or the Directory).

My question here is: will variables that I define within the thread_task function be shared with other threads, thus needing the threading.Lock() function to be invoked? Or can I remove the Lock condition?

```py
import numpy as np
import math as mm
import glob
import sys
import os
import shutil
import threading


import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from numpy import genfromtxt
from io import StringIO, BytesIO

import glob_general_functions as gf
import glob_sput_count as scg
import glob_file_interpretation as figl
import glob_bond_gr as bgg
import glob_bond_length as blg
import glob_probe_follow as prf

def main_task(nb_cores,length_analyse):
    lock = threading.Lock()
    thread_list = ['thread_'+str(i) for i in range(nb_cores)]
    for i in range(0,length_analyse,nb_cores):
        for j in range(nb_cores):
            thread_list[i]=threading.Thread(target=thread_task, args=(lock,files_to_analyse[i+j],))
            thread_list[i].start()
            thread_list[i].join()
        print("Threading Done !")       


def thread_task(lock,file_to_analyse):
    """
    task for thread
    calls the functions and process them
    """
    lock.acquire()
    file = os.path.split(file_to_analyse)[1].replace('.lammps', '')
    Directory = DirBase + os.path.split(file_to_analyse)[0] + '/'
    temp_file_init, temp_file1_init, temp_file2_init, pos_file_init, bond_file_init, ext_init, ext2_init, Dir_init, nb_atoms_init, header_length_init, dim_x_init, dim_y_init, dim_z_init, box_size_init, read_file_init, line_file_init = figl.interpolation(file, Directory)
    pos_file_inter, sputt_particles, ext2_inter, len_atoms_sputt, figs, csvData_sputt = scg.sput_count_glob(file, temp_file_init, temp_file1_init, temp_file2_init, pos_file_init, bond_file_init, ext_init, ext2_init, Dir_init, nb_atoms_init, header_length_init, dim_x_init, dim_y_init, dim_z_init, box_size_init, read_file_init, line_file_init, delta, epsilon)
    if pos_file_inter == 0:
        pass
    else:
        for j in range(len_atoms_sputt):
            fig_traj = figs[j]
            plt.savefig(file+'_'+sputt_particles[j]+ext2_init)

    fig_median, graph_title, csvData_bond =  blg.bond_length_glob(file, temp_file_init, bond_file_init, ext_init, ext2_init, Dir_init, nb_atoms_init, header_length_init, dim_x_init, dim_y_init, dim_z_init, box_size_init, read_file_init, line_file_init, cut_off, delta)
    plt.savefig(graph_title)

    fig_probe, csvData1_probe, csvData2_probe = prf.probe_follow_glob(file, temp_file_init, pos_file_init, ext_init, ext2_init, Dir_init, nb_atoms_init, header_length_init, dim_x_init, dim_y_init, dim_z_init, box_size_init, read_file_init, line_file_init, m_probe)
    plt.savefig(pos_file_init+ext2_init)

    fig_gr, grr, csvData_gr = bgg.bond_gr_glob(file, temp_file_init, bond_file_init, ext_init, ext2_init, Dir_init, nb_atoms_init, header_length_init, dim_x_init, dim_y_init, dim_z_init, box_size_init, read_file_init, line_file_init, n_bins, cut_off, delta)
    plt.savefig(file+grr)
    lock.release()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: In particular, you have not demonstrated a specific coding problem.  You've asked us a pair of related questions that are directly answerable by running your code -- which, after all, is the ultimate answer.  It's not reasonable to expect us to read your code -- especially with all of the overhead -- and render an accurate answer.  When you run into a problem, post a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is "the thread function?" Are you asking about `thread_task()` in your example? That's just a normal function that your program calls from within a new `Thread`. What are "thread variables?" Are you asking about the _local_ variables in `thread_task()`? Those are just like the local variables of any other normal function. They belong to a particular _[activation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Structure)_ of the function. They are created when the function is called, destroyed when the function returns, and they are inaccessible to any other activation of the same function.

Comment: Are you familiar with the GIL, Python's Global Interpreter Lock? It's likely to cause you some grief, even if your code was correctly starting your threads to run in parallel. You probably need `multiprocessing` instead of `threading`, though the overhead of interprocess communication might eat up most of the performance benefits of running things in parallel.

Comment: I read your comments and will comply to it for the future. In this example I admit I wasn't clear enough in what I wanted to know. If I ask other questions, I will be more specific (@Prune)
My question was: Are the variable that are created in the thre thread_task function would be called inbetween threads, but SolomonSlow answered my question perfectly. Thank you !
Also thank you Blckknght for your suggestion, I will definitively give it a closer look !